# Get Only Nested Key-Value Pairs From Dictionary?

Tags: python

Given the following dictionary in python, I'm interested in getting only inner key-value pairs.

```
{
  "destination": {
    "name": "accountName"
  },
  "orderData": {
    "sourceOrderId": "1234512345",
    "items": [
      {
        "sku": "Business Cards",
        "sourceItemId": "1234512346",
        "components": [
          {
            "code": "Content",            
            "fetch": true,
            "path": "http://www.w2psite.com/businessCard.pdf"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "shipments": [
      {
        "shipTo": {
          "name": "John Doe",
          "companyName": "Acme"
        },
        "carrier":{
          "code": "fedex",
          "service": "ground"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In other words I want:

```
name: accountName
sourceOrderId: 1234512345
sku: Business Cards
sourceItemId: 1234512346
```

etc... and I don't want:

```
destination, orderData etc...
```

How can I do this?

**Few things to Note:**

1. I don't want `"` to be in output
2. There could be multiple inner values and what I showed is just an example.

I tried:

```
for key, value in json_f.items():
    print(key, value)
```

But it's not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to traverse an arbitrarily nested structure is usually a recursive function, e.g.:

```
>>> def print_inner_json(obj):
...     for k, v in obj.items():
...         if isinstance(v, list):
...             for i in v:
...                 if isinstance(i, dict):
...                     print_inner_json(i)
...         elif isinstance(v, dict):
...             print_inner_json(v)
...         else:
...             print(f"{k}: {v}")
...
>>> import json
>>> print_inner_json(json.loads(json_f))
name: accountName
sourceOrderId: 1234512345
sku: Business Cards
sourceItemId: 1234512346
code: Content
fetch: True
path: http://www.w2psite.com/businessCard.pdf
name: John Doe
companyName: Acme
code: fedex
service: ground
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I save results in list instead of printing them? I mean something like: ['name', 'accountName', 'sourceOrderId', '1234512345'...]

Comment: Create a list (outside the function) and replace the `print(...)` with `your_list.append(...)`.

Comment: Isn't there a way to create the list inside?

Comment: Yes, but then you need to change more lines of code.  Each time you make a recursive call, `extend` your list with its result, and then return your list at the end.

Answer (score -1):

```
json_obj = {
  "destination": {
    "name": "accountName"
  },
  "orderData": {
    "sourceOrderId": "1234512345",
    "items": [
      {
        "sku": "Business Cards",
        "sourceItemId": "1234512346",
        "components": [
          {
            "code": "Content",            
            "fetch": True,
            "path": "http://www.w2psite.com/businessCard.pdf"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "shipments": [
      {
        "shipTo": {
          "name": "John Doe",
          "companyName": "Acme"
        },
        "carrier":{
          "code": "fedex",
          "service": "ground"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

name = json_obj["destination"]["name"]
source_order_id = json_obj["orderData"]["sourceOrderId"]
sku = json_obj["orderData"]["items"][0]["sku"]
source_item_id = json_obj["orderData"]["items"][0]["sourceItemId"]
print(name)
print(source_order_id)
print(sku)
print(source_item_id)
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question and ignores my notes :(

Comment: "Just hardcode what you want" is usually not an acceptable solution

Comment: @LOG What is an example of multiple inner keys being in the JSON response? This was just an example how to specifically get the name/source order id/ sku, and source item id from the JSON response. for the SKY and source item id, you can use a for loop to iterate over all orderData